# Get yaxis value from xaxis Plotly

Tags: r, plotly

If i have xaxis value (e.g. 20) how can y get yaxis?
Specifically the xaxis to be used is the `tail` from `lm()` and I want mark by `add_trace()` this xaxis and yaxis on the curve. Using `plot_ly()` is essential for manual interaction with the chart.

```
xfit <- seq(rnorm(100))
yfit <- dnorm(xfit, mean(xfit), sd(xfit))

Chart <- plot_ly() %>%  
  add_lines(x = xfit,
            y = yfit)

ggplotly(Chart)
```